# How to handle menu items in C# for passing values

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu, menuitem

I am working in Windows Forms in C#. I have a method where I am adding `MenuItem`s to the `ContextMenu` and I implemented the event handlers for the `MenuItem`s as below:

```
public void Form1_Load()
{
    int index = 0;
    ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
    ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
    cm.Name = "Test";
    MenuItem mi = new MenuItem("All");
    mi.Click += new EventHandler(mi_All);
}

private void mi_All(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Here I want to access the arraylist and integer specified in above method
}
```

How can this be done? One possible solution is to declare the `ArrayList` and `int` as global variables, but I have a lot of variables like this. If I take this approach, the variables will live until the form gets disposed. So this doesn't work. Is there another way of achieving this?

Comment: The question is why do you need to access the array list?  Consider using the tag property of the menu item for extra storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MenuItem` has a `Tag` property that can be used to assign any custom information you like. So assign to this whatever you need to access when the event handler is invoked. In your example you would assign the integer index of the enu item and then inside the event handler use that as the index into the Form level ArrayList field.

Answer (score 5):

One option:

```
mi.Click += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e) { mi_All(sender, e, ar, index); };
...
private void mi_All(object sender, EventArgs e, ArrayList ar, int index)
{
   ...
}
```

Another:

```
mi.Tag = new object[] { ar, index };
...
private void mi_All(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList ar = (ArrayList)((object[])((MenuItem)sender).Tag)[0];
    int index = (int)((object[])((MenuItem)sender).Tag)[1];
    ...
}
```

Comment: I can do this for accessing. Thanks for the solution. Similarly if I want to return the index which will be updated in event handler method, any way exists for this. Please let me know.